# Php mysql, variable help query help

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have this mysql query:

```
UPDATE `table`.`wp_12_postmeta` 
   SET `meta_value` = 'yyy' 
 WHERE `wp_12_postmeta`.`meta_id` =5 
 LIMIT 1 ;
```

How do i incorporate this:

- instead of `wp_12_` i want a variable `$prefix` (variable holds wp_4_, wp_3_, etc)
- instead of `yyy` i want a value `$perf`  (variable is a name )
- instead of `5` i want a value `$meta_id` (variable is a nr)

Thank u!

P.S.

here is what i use and it works:

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE ".$prefix."postmeta SET meta_value = '".$perf."' WHERE meta_id = '".$meta_id."' LIMIT 1 ");
```

Problem is, when i execute this query, severl post meta fields are updated, instead of just one.
 Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write this with PDO:

```
$prefix = "wp_4_";
$sql = "UPDATE `table`.`{$prefix}postmeta` SET `meta_value` = ? 
  WHERE `{$prefix}postmeta`.`meta_id` = ? LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($perf, $meta_id));
```

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the $prefix?

Comment: @Codeacula: The $prefix is a string I have hard-coded in the above example.  It doesn't come from an untrusted source.  Besides, what function would you suggest I use that would escape a back-tick?  Certainly mysql_real_escape_string() doesn't do that.

Comment: You have it hardcoded, yes, but I'd be willing to bet the OP would use the code as-is, and that $prefix would likely end up getting changed by who knows what source. And perhaps it's paranoia that causes me to want to sanitize every single variable that comes from user input. To each their own, I guess.

Comment: @Codeacula: I do support defensive programming and being mindful of SQL injection risks.  See http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies  What would you suggest is the best remedy in this case?

Comment: Go with the remedy you provided at the end, I guess. And, if you don't mind, I'm going to share your report.

Comment: @Codeacula:  Yes, be my guest!  Also, I'll be presenting that talk at ZendCon in Santa Clara in November 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE `table`.`%s` 
                    SET `meta_value` = '%s' 
                  WHERE `%s`.`meta_id` = %d 
                   LIMIT 1 ",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($prefix),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($perf),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($prefix),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($meta_id));
```

Comment: You forgot the wp_12_ in the WHERE, also.

Comment: +1 because I always love sprintf over the usual concatenation for queries. Especially manageable when you're writing a headache of a query.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() is not the right solution for table or column identifiers.  If for no other reason than it does not escape the back-tick: `

Comment: @Bill, I think the back ticks should be included around the `%s`

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: I agree, but like Bill says--mysql_real_escape_string won't escape a lone bactick